# How to determine which NSCollectionViewItems are actually visible

Tags: uikit, nscollectionview

I am using an `NSCollectionView`, which shows images that I need to render in the background. This rendering takes significant time (e.g. 100ms to more than a second).

I use a regular flow layout (`NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`) with same-sized `NSCollectionViewItem` tiles.

Once the collectionView is going live, it creates many more item instances (tiles) than are actually fitting into the current view. For instance, if 6 tiles fit into the view, it asked for about 20 tiles. I start a rending process for each created tile. Once an image has been rendered, the tile gets notified, which in turn causes to refresh its view.

Now, while the rending is going on, the user may scroll downward, e.g. to the last 6 tiles. This creates a performance problem:

There are still lots of renderings in the queue for tiles that were not visible yet and won't be visible any time soon, either (they were skipped over by the user when he scrolled directly to the end). The collectionView, now requestion the views for the now visible last 6 tiles will drop 6 of its previously allocated ones, 4 of which may have been already rendered and marked dropping anyway, so only 2 of the remaining 16 tiles in the rendering queue will be notified that they won't be needed and be removed from the queue. And the newly visible 6 tiles from the end will get appended to the rendering queue.

This means that, before the user starts seeing any images from where he scrolled to, 14 more images will have to be rendered even though they're not shown in the current collection view's content area.

How can I optimize this, so that, when the user scrolls, I immediately start rendering the newest visible `NSCollectionViewItem`s? None of the delegate functions seem to help with this. Even functions like `visibleItems` return not just the visible ones but all the ones the collectionView allocated, including the 14 invisible ones.

I could, when adding items to the queue, always insert them to the front, instead of appending them to the end of the queue. That would not help either, though, because then, initially, when the collectionView asks for 20 tiles, I'd end up rendering the 20th tile first, and thus end up not showing any renderings until 14 invisible ones have been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for `-[NSCollectionView visibleItems]`:

> This array may contain items that are outside of the collection view’s actual visible rectangle. For example, it may contain items that were recently visible but have since been scrolled out of view. To test whether an item is actually visible, check to see if its frame rectangle intersects the visibleRect of the collection view.

So, here's a function that performs this test, returning the actually visible items only:

```
- (NSArray<NSCollectionViewItem*> * _Nonnull) trulyVisibleItemsInCollectionView:(NSCollectionView*)collectionView
{
    NSMutableArray<NSCollectionViewItem*> *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray<NSCollectionViewItem *> *items = collectionView.visibleItems;
    NSRect viewRect = collectionView.visibleRect;
    for (NSCollectionViewItem *item in items) {
        if (NSIntersectsRect(item.view.frame, viewRect)) {
            [result addObject:item];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This still makes it difficult to manage the rendering queue efficiently, though:

1. When my `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` gets invoked, the views are not added to the collectionView yet, so that's too early to determine whether this tile should be scheduled for immediate rendering.
2. A timer might be used to periodically check which items are visible, and move them to the front of the queue. It should not be used to decide whether to insert items into the queue, because, if the timer fires too early after a tile object has been created, it won't be added to the view yet, which would lead to more delay until the rendering starts. Therefore, I believe it's best to add items to the renderer as soon as it's know they might be needed, but reorder the queue once it's clear which items will be visible and which won't.